# Booting linux kernel with big ramdisk

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, ramdisk

I built a ramdisk image which is bigger than 16 MB. After downloading the ramdisk image U-boot print:

```
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   uboot ext4 ramdisk rootfs
   Created:      2018-01-24   8:15:12 UTC
   Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    38319491 Bytes = 36.5 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 01000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x1000000
   Loading Ramdisk to 3d567000, end 3f9f2583 ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 0000000001000000, end 000000000100c554

Starting kernel ...

Timer summary in microseconds:
       Mark    Elapsed  Stage
          0          0  reset
  1,106,000  1,106,000  id=64
  1,437,000    331,000  id=65
  1,445,000      8,000  main_loop
102,482,800,0,02,338,300,0, id=80
102,482,800,0          0  tftp_start
102,482,800,0,         0  eth_start
102,985,300,0, 5,025,000  id=81
102,985,300,0          0  id=84
102,985,300,0          0  id=82
102,985,300,0          0  tftp_done
104,389,500,0,14,042,000  bootm_start
104,734,100,0, 3,446,000  id=9
104,734,100,0          0  id=10
105,199,700,0  4,656,000  id=11
105,200,400,0      7,000  id=12
105,821,800,0  6,214,000  id=15
105,822,000,0      2,000  start_kernel
166,835,917,366,575,094,88166,835,917,355,992,894,88  board_init_f

Accumulated time:
```

==================================================================

Kernel is hanging.
But if the ramdisk image is smaller than 16 MB, it works.
What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: *"if the ramdisk image is smaller than 16 MB, it works"* -- Duh, so what is the allocated size of this ramdisk (i.e. **/dev/ram0**) in the kernel config?  BTW what's the purpose of using a journaled filesystem in a ramdisk?  *"What can I do to fix this problem?"* -- An initramfs can dynamically be any size up to available memory.

Comment: This is my kernel config: CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=100000.@sawdust

Comment: Please provide a full boot log including up to where the process fails, along with a 'printenv' in U-Boot, thanks!